# transform-box: content-box, border-box and stroke-box "invalid property value" Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: css, svg, google-chrome-devtools, css-transforms

The [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) state that the following are all valid properties:

```
transform-box: content-box;
transform-box: border-box;
transform-box: fill-box;
transform-box: stroke-box;
transform-box: view-box;
```

It also states that all current (November 2021) browsers have full support, except IE11 of course. [Caniuse.com confirms](https://caniuse.com/?search=transform-box) this browser support for `transform-box`.

However, when I attempt to use `transform-box: content-box;`, `transform-box: border-box;` or `transform-box: stroke-box;`, Chrome Dev Tools reports these as "invalid property values":

[image: Chrome Dev Tools displaying "Invalid property value"]

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=924472